# How does the reputation on parent and on meta site work?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The meta site shows the reputation of the parent site Super User at the top.

The activity of this meta site shows I have earned reputation, are these added to the parent site?

This would allow one to get reputation past the daily reputation cap, is that the right behavior?

Answer (score 11):

On meta.superuser.com (or any meta site with the exception of meta.stackoverflow.com) you don't actually gain or lose any reputation. Your reputation score is tied to the parent site and up or downvotes on the meta site have no bearing on your reputation.

> **Reputation is always inherited from the parent site.** You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.

Source: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Comment: Why is there a reputation tab on the meta site? Shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: @Tom, It is till nice to use reputation as a gauge of the credibility of the person who is asking or answering a question.  I trust an answer from a higher rep much more than a user who only has 20 rep.

Comment: @TomWij: Some of the reputation bits have already been removed (eg. the reputation graph). Removed entirely to simplify matters? I think that's a good idea.