# Where can I ask about "Google Reader"?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

Is this the right place to ask a question about RSS feed items in [Google Reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Reader)?

If not, on which Stack Exchange site can I ask such a question?

Comment: FYI @Meysam, with respect to your question elsewhere about reputation on meta: [You don't earn reputation on local metas](http://meta.superuser.com/a/1258/39366), your rep score here is simply a copy from the main SU site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Exchange site *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)* would be the proper site to ask about this:

> Web Applications - Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> - Bookmarklets
> - Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)